# Расширить enum для отображения в UI в dropDown-е, asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

В приложении есть enum, который является частью модели и его расширение невозможно. (Тип создан исключительно для примера)

```
public enum Cars : int
{
    Nissan = 1,
    Kia,
    Toyota,
    BMW
}
```

Во View есть dropDown. Помимо уже имеющихся значений, необходимо что бы dropDown также содержал как минимум записи "All" и "None", но возможны и другие. Это необходимо для фильтрации. Необходимо понимать, что выбранное в dropDown-e значение будет отсылаться обратно на сервер, и будет сравниваться со свойством типа `enum Cars` у имеющихся доменных объектов.
Как лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: А что должно прийти на сервер, если будет выбрано `All`? Расскажите подробнее, какую логику вы кодируете.

Comment: @VladD любое int значение. К примеру можно закодировать All = 99, None = 100. Это не принципиально. Можете предложить свой вариант.

Comment: Так почему бы эти значения All и None не добавить в enum ?

Comment: @null Нельзя изменять исходный enum.

Comment: @Suneption: А что должен делать сервер, если к нему придёт значение `All`? Он готов к такому повороту событий?

Comment: @VladD да, если All, то сервер просто возвращает все записи, т.е. без фильтрации.

Comment: Ну тогда запихнуть в дропдаун значения All - 0 (выбрать все) и None (-1) ничего не выбирать и потом уже смотреть что пришло на сервер.

Comment: @null а как бы это лучше сделать, что бы избежать дублирования кода и хардкодинга?

Comment: Ну сделайте какой-нибудь хелпер который будет выдавать List<SelectListItem> с этим двумя значениями, а потом к нему добавлять основные значения.

Comment: @Suneption: Ээ, не, так не пойдёт. А откуда _сервер_-то знает, какое у нас числовое значение для `All`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим ли вариант создания нового перечислания таким образом?

```
public enum Cars : int
{
    Nissan = 1,
    Kia,
    Toyota,
    BMW
}

public enum CarsExtension: int
{
    None = -1,
    All = 999,
    Nissan = Cars.Nissan,
    Kia = Cars.Kia,
    Toyota  = Cars.Toyota,
    BMW = Cars.BMW
}
```

Comment: Это опасно. Представьте себе, что в `Cars` добавили ещё одну константу, тогда `CarsExtension` будет неправильным, и при компиляции это не поймается.

Comment: >  Нельзя изменять исходный enum //подходит, если исходный енум нельзя менять

Comment: Я понимал «нельзя» как «не принадлежит нам». Но владельцы этого энума вполне могут его поменять. Ну и менять модельный объект по желанию/прихоти кода уровня отображения как-то уж совсем неправильно.

Comment: Согласен, но что поделать, я предложил вариант, который, возможно, автор не рассматривал, помимо очевидных: не передавать ничего при выборе None и отметить все значения при выборе All, т.е. немного js или checkboxlist/multiselect, а на сервере принимать перечисление выбранных вариантов). + допустимость использования совсем неясна. пусть решает автор вопроса.

Comment: т.е. вот такой списочек наверняка рассматривался http://jsfiddle.net/1moqhpu7/ (без js только представил и так ясно как должно работать), а на серверной стороне принимать в action string[] selectedValues

Comment: Возможно, если исходный enum имеет «флаговый» вид (`Nissan = 1`, `Kia = 2`, `Toyota = 4`, `BMW = 8` и т. д.), можно передавать битовую комбинацию. НО сервер должен быть к этому готов.

Comment: Наверное, `HashSet<Cars>` было бы самым правильным решением.

Comment: Битовые были бы удобны, но в представленном коде элементы перечисления некоторые не привязаны к значению, так что этот вариант отбросил сразу